# codeigniter configure the folder structure

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, filepath

My file structure look like this:

```
.
└── htdocs
    └── projects // contain all my projects
        └── <name-of-website> // a specific project
            ├── application
            ├── system
            ├── index.php
            ├── css
            └── js
```

so the url on the browser look like this (I have also removed the index.php):

```
localhost/projects/<name-of-website>
```

What I'd like to do is to put the **index.php the css and the js inside a public_html folder, like this:**

```
.
└── htdocs
    └── projects
        └── <name-of-website>
            ├── application
            ├──  system
            └── public_html
                ├── css
                ├── js
                ├── index.php
                └── .htaccess
```

and also changed the paths to the **system and the application folder**:

```
$system_path = '../system';
$application_folder = '../application';
```

but when I try the url again I don't get access to the index page, instead have to go to `http://localhost/projects/fakecms/<name-of-website>/` .

My question is can I keep the folder structure like this without braking the url?? basicly I want to access the index.php like this `http://localhost/projects/<name-of-website>` again

Comment: put your htacess in public html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*IMHO, doing this on `localhost` doesn't make a sense for me, BTW:*

Instead of moving the `index.php` file, you could move your `application` and `system` folder somewhere outside the `htdocs` (or `public_html` on the server) directory and change the paths of those two folder according the directory tree.

There's usually a `.htaccess` file inside those two folder which prevent direct accessing the PHP files (by `Deny from all`).

However, Moving those folders outside of the web root, improves the security if the `.htaccess` stops working for any reason.

For instance, if your `index.php` file is located at `/home/public_html/project/`, the `application` and `system` folders should be placed at `/home/` path:

```
home
  application
  system
  public_html
    project
      css
      js
      .htaccess
      index.php
```

And the paths would be:

```php
$system_path        = '../../system';
$application_folder = '../../application';
```

Comment: You mean this structure makes sence when a project is on a server??

Comment: @Lykos Yes, on the **production environment**

Comment: Yes I have noticed the .htaccess files and also all php files contain this line of code: defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access.'); to ensure the script can't be accessed directly. I dont want to remove the application and system folder outside the folder of my project, it will become a mess with all my other projects. However if I upload this on a server I'll try to follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you can make your css and js like that and define your path in constants.php like that

```
define('STYLESHEETS_PATH',      'yoururl/css/');
define('SCRIPTS_PATH',          'yoururl/js/');
```

when getting css you just `echo $STYLESHEETS_PATH;` or for js `echo $SCRIPTS_PATH`